# How do I add spaces to folder names being created in Event Viewer > Application and Services logs?

Tags: c#, etw, event-viewer, etw-eventsource

Currently, I'm using [EventSourceAttribute](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/microsoft-diagnostics-tracing-eventsource-is-now-stable/#sending-events-to-the-windows-event-log) to create a hierarchy of subfolders in Application and Services log in Event Viewer. This is my code

```
[EventSource(Name = "Service-MacClient-EventSource")]
public sealed class MinimalEventSource : EventSource
{
    public static MinimalEventSource Log = new MinimalEventSource();

    [Event(1, Channel = EventChannel.Operational, Message = "{0}", Level = EventLevel.Informational)]
    public void Info(string msg)
    {
        WriteEvent(1, msg);
    }
}
```

In Application and Services logs, the folders came out to be `Service > MacClient > EventSource`.

[image]

However, what I wanted was spaces between every capital letters in the folder names e.g. `Service > Mac Client > Event Source`. So I tried to change it to

```
[EventSource(Name = "Service-Mac Client-Event Source")]
```

But unfortunately, I encountered this error while building my project

> MSXML Schema Validation Error 0xc00ce169. At Line=4, Column=426, 'ServiceMac ClientEvent Source' violates pattern constraint of '()|([_a-zA-Z][_0-9a-zA-Z]*)'.

May I know how do I add spaces to folder names that are being created in Event Viewer > Application and Services please? Thanks in advance!

**Additional notes**

Microsoft's User Experience Virtualization seems to show that adding spaces for names of subfolders in Application and Services log in Event Viewer is possible.

[image]